# Prove: Sum and Difference of two distinct positive integers are both perfect squares.

Tags: number-theory, logic

I'm trying to prove that there exists two distinct positive integers whose sum and difference are both perfect squares. I cannot find any pattern or characteristic between the pairs of numbers that work i.e.

- 4, 5
- 6, 10
- 8, 17
- 10, 6
- 10, 26

Any help will be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let those positive integers be $a$ and $b$.Then,

$a+b=x^2$

$a-b=y^2$

Adding the two we get $a=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ and $b=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2}$

Since, a and b are integers we must have $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2-y^2$ must be even, for that we must have x and y both even or both odd.

Now for finding such pairs take any even $x,y$ for example let x=8 and y=4

which gives $a=40$ and $b=24$, we have $a+b=64=8^2$ and $a-b=16=4^2$

Comment: Ramanujan would be proud (+1)

Comment: @J.W.Perry Thank you,appreciated.

Comment: This proof is great! Well done! :)

Comment: @RossBelgram Thank you, appreciated.